# Pass object to PHP through AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I was wondering if it is possible to pass an array to a php function using the jQuery AJAX function. I have the following as my javascript

```
arr_data = {
    field01: "data 01",
    field02: "data 02",
    field03: "data 03",
    field04: "data 04"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/php/phpfunc.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'action': "exec_find",
        'field01': arr_data["field01"],
        'field02': arr_data["field02"],
        'field03': arr_data["field03"],
        'field04': arr_data["field04"]
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // continue program
    },
    error: function(log) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

When I try to do the following though

```
arr_data = {
    field01: "data 01",
    field02: "data 02",
    field03: "data 03",
    field04: "data 04"
}

$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/php/phpfunc.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'action': "exec_find",
        'data': arr_data
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // continue program
    },
    error: function(log) {
        // handle error
    }
});
```

I receive it in the PHP as "Array". How can I correctly send the object so that it is usable by the PHP function?

Comment: from the second ajax you can access the data like: $_GET['data']['field01']

Comment: As you are sending the data as json , use json_decode in php function to convert the json to PHP array and then you can parse it

Comment: Just FYI, what you're sending is an object. I updated the question accordingly

Comment: Thanks for assistance @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: No wonder if you are sending object or object value as an array .. php will receive it in array in REQUEST [post/get]

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem @madalinivascu I didn't realize the field names still applied in the php code, could you post an answer so that I can accept it as correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from the second ajax you can access the data based on the property names like: `$_GET['data']['field01']`

`$_GET['data']` is the js object converted in php in a associative array

Answer (score 9):

Please try to pass the array in the format of json. Then use the get the json in your php and access the json array.

```
<script>

arr_data = {
    field01: "data 01",
    field02: "data 02",
    field03: "data 03",
    field04: "data 04"
}
var  myJsonString= JSON.stringify(arr_data);
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/php/phpfunc.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'action': "exec_find",
        'data': myJsonString
    },
    success: function(result) {
        // continue program
    },
    error: function(log) {
        // handle error
    }
});
</script>
```

this is your java script. and below is the php

```
$dataJson=json_decode($_GET['data']);
```

here you can get the json array and loop through it and do what ever you want.

Please have try at this. This is working in my case.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```js
$.ajax({
    url: "scripts/php/phpfunc.php",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        'action': "exec_find",
        'data': arr_data.serialize()
    },
```

serialize()

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

convert your array in string