# Get multiple filter value parameters

Tags: php, query-string

I'm using this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43668518/jquery-add-multiple-filter-parameters-to-url) to handle my filter search using checkbox.

This is the JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e) {
      var data = {},
          fdata = [],
          loc = $('<a>', { href: window.location })[0];
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i) {
          if (this.checked) {
              if (!data.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                  data[this.name] = [];
              }
              data[this.name].push(this.value);
          }
      });
      // get all keys.
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      var fdata = "";
      // iterate over them and create the fdata
      keys.forEach(function(key,i){
          if (i>0) fdata += '&'; // if its not the first key add &
          fdata += key+"="+data[key].join(',');
      });
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/ajax/get",
        data: {
              "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
              "fdata": fdata
            },
        success: function (response) {
          $('#d2d-results').html(response);
        }
      });
      if (history.pushState) {
          history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname + '?' + fdata);
      }
  });
```

And now I try to get the value of fdata to PHP.

On PHP I get this value of variable `echo $_GET['fdata'];`:

```
discount=Y&brand=BR0006,BR0003
```

What I want

```
$discount="Y";
$brand="BR0006,BR0003";
```

Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: save `fdata` as an object

Comment: Hi @Hikarunomemory could you give me an example?

Comment: have you tried `$_GET['fdata']['discount'];`?

Comment: Just tried and got error: `Warning: Illegal string offset 'discount' in `

Comment: here's a similar post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525547/pass-object-to-php-through-ajax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you want, you have to do two steps:

1. [parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) the **query string** into an array:

   ```
   parse_str($_GET['fdata'], $result);
   ```
2. And then, [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) the array as variables:

   ```
   extract($result);
   ```

---

A few things to note:

Using `extract` is very insecure (and somewhat ugly). The user can put things like (for example) `isAdmin=1` in the URL and the will affect your code. Basically, you cannot trust your variables anymore.

I would skip step 2 (the `extract` thingy), and use `$result` directly, for example `echo $result['discount']`.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you are mixing post and get, is it something like this that you're after?

via GET:

```
if(isset($_GET['discount'])) {
    $discount = $_GET['discount'];
} else {
    $discount = '';
}

if(isset($_GET['brand'])) {
    $brand = $_GET['brand'];
} else {
    $brand = '';
}
```

POST method:

```
if(isset($_POST['discount'])) {
    $discount = $_POST['discount'];
} else {
    $discount = '';
}

if(isset($_POST['brand'])) {
    $brand = $_POST['brand'];
} else {
    $brand = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in one way , you can use explode function in php to separate your item from fdata

you can define some character in your client JS app for example ( , ) and then in explode function in php you must set separator equal comma character

explode function in PHP

```
explode(separator,string,limit)
```

in your example separator is comma and string is fdata ( limit optional
)

```
$fdata = $_GET['fdata'];
$arr_ = explode('&',$fdata);
```

and if you have some thing like this in fdata string

```
para1=223&para2=4353&para3=234
```

then $arr_ variable like this

```
$arr_ = [para1=223 , para2=4353 , para3=234];
```

and if you want separate  value and key , you can do this again and use loop